# Proper way to test if a value is numeric in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I just need to know if the value is numeric. I don't need to do anything with the value. Is this the best way? Feel dirty creating a variable that I won't ever use beyond this:

```
int val;
if(int.TryParse(txtFoo.Text, out val))
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: `123.45` is numeric, but will fail this check.  Are you testing for integers only?

Comment: there is a char.IsNumeric function, if I remember right

Comment: @Winston Smith - that's out of context of this question as 123.45 would never apply to an int. If that was the case they'd use a float and do float.TryParse.

Comment: @thedixon - that was my point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using the relevant `TryParse` method and ignoring the `out` parameter is the best way of doing this.

You may want to wrap this up into your own set of helper methods (which could specify the appropriate culture etc, if the default isn't right for you) and just return a `bool` without the `out` parameter to make them easier to call.

Of course, you need to work out what kind of parsing is most appropriate - even for integers, you need to consider whether the range of `Int32` is enough for your use case. In my experience, most numeric input has its own "natural" range of valid values, which is unlikely to be exactly the range of any predefined type. You may therefore want to expand your helper methods to include the range of valid values to accept.

Comment: If Int32 isn't big enough, and he has .Net 4, he could use `System.Numerics.BigInteger.TryParse()`

Comment: @C. Lawrence Wenham: Don't forget poor, neglected `Int64`!

Comment: @LukeH: Yeah, but `BigInteger` "goes to 11".

Comment: @C. Lawrence Wenham: Love it. Wouldn't it be fab to have a language where the normal integer types only coped with [-10, 10], but BigInteger went to 11?

Answer (score 3):

"is numeric" is an ambiguous term.

- Culture-aware?
- Allow thousands and/or decimal separators?
- Allow scientific notation?
- Allow a sign (before? after?...)
- What range of values do you allow?  Signed 32-bit integer (Int32.TryParse), Unsigned 32-bit integer (UInt32.TryParse), decimal, double, ...

Hence there is no "best" way, and the Framework provides a multitude of different ways to parse numbers.

Answer (score 2):

It's not as flexible as `int.TryParse`, but you could check to see if each character is a number:

```
bool isInt = txtFoo.Text.All(c => char.IsNumber(c));
```

In general, though, I would recommend sticking with `int.TryParse`.  You can even call the unused parameter "ignored" to be explicit about your intent, e.g.:

```
int ignored;
bool isInt = int.TryParse(txtFoo.Text, out ignored);
```

Comment: You'd have to add handling for `'+'`, `'-'`, `','`, `'.'`, `'E'`, and `'e'`, and perhaps some others I'm overlooking, because these are non-numeric characters that can appear in a numeric string.

Comment: @phoog: absolutely agreed, which was why I recommended `int.TryParse` in the end. I was just offering an alternative way of looking at the problem under more constrained conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regular expressions

```
Regex _isNumber = new Regex(@"^\d+$");
_isNumber.IsMatch(txtFoo.Text);
```

This will only match Ints, but you can write one that also matches decimals.

Answer (score 1):

That is the recommended way of doing it in C#. However, you could also add `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` as a reference to your project and then use `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsNumeric()`

Answer (score 0):

That's the best way of doing it in my knowledge - that's what our company standards adhere to anyway due to the error handling being done within the parsing.

This details the advantages: https://web.archive.org/web/20150510214425/http://www.dotnetperls.com:80/int-tryparse

Comment: updated link via the way back machine; original `tryparse` is no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Regex parsing to determine that there are no non-numeric characters in a string, or you can use Int.TryParse(), Double.TryParse(), Float.TryParse() depending on the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool test (string teststring) 
 { for (i=0;i==teststring.length;i++){
   if instr("0123456789.,-+Ee",teststring.substring(i,1) <0){return false;}
   // some additional tests below here if you like
   return true;
 }
```

however  E1001E12e.12e  would be noted as a number a little bit more magic is needed to do a  clean check, but then you might be able to determine if its a int or a float too..